# Delete in Exact target

Tags: marketing-cloud

How to get fetched all sendid from tracking list? I want to clear my tracking list.Is this even possible? Also clear list ,subscriber ,tracking information and all everything. I have done the delete list and subscriber.I want clear dashboard.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. It seems like there are 2-3 different questions here.

Comment: I want to clear dashboard data. Also clear my tracking information.

Answer (score 3):

You are not able to delete tracking data.  The [documentation here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/methods/delete/) shows what objects are allowed for use with the `delete` method.

Comment: I want delete tracking send data in dashboard Tracking->Sends  - shows the emaild. I want clear those emailid.

Comment: If you look at the documentation, tracking data is not able to be deleted.